# Why does strtok() not tokenize the string a certain way?

Tags: c, string, tokenize, strtok

I'm trying to tokenize a string using brackets [] as delimiters. I can tokenize a string exactly how I want it with one input, but it has an error other times. For example, I have a string with characters before the delimiter and it works fine, but if nothing is before the delimiter then I run into errors.

This one gives me an error. The `token2` ends up being `NULL` and `token` is `"name]"`  with the bracket still on there.

```
char name[] = "[name]";
char *token = strtok(name, "[");
char *token2 = strtok(NULL, "]");
```

Output:

```
token = name]
token2 = NULL
```

However, if I have the following, then it works just fine.

```
char line[] = "Hello [name]";
char *tok = strtok(line, "[");
char *tok2 = strtok(NULL, "]");
```

Output:

```
tok = Hello
tok2 = name
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong when the input is simply something like `"[name]"`. I want just what's inside the brackets only.

Edit:
Thanks for the input, everyone. I found a solution to what I'm trying to do. Per @Ryan and @StoryTeller's advice, I first checked if the input began with `[` and delimited with `[]`. Here's what I tried and worked for the input:

```
char name[] = "[name]", *token = NULL, *token2 = NULL;

if (name[0] == '[')
{
    token = strtok(name, "[]");
}
else
{
    token = strtok(name, "[");
    token2 = strtok(NULL, "]");
}
```

Comment: The tokens `strtok` returns are never empty, so the first `[`-delimited token in `"[name]"` is `"name]"`. You can do a manual check to see if the input starts with `'['` to avoid that.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I use visual studio and in my locals window it tells me that the value is NULL, "token2 0x00000000 <NULL>". Also, strtok does return a null pointer if there are no more tokens to be retrieved.

Comment: That's because `strtok` return `NULL` when it encounters the end of the input. After `]` is the end.

Comment: @StoryTeller, thanks I get that part now. What should I do to get only "name" from the string?

Comment: There's a reason the second parameter is a pointer to a string. You can specify several tokens, like `"]["`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*In short*: the 2nd time you called `strtok()` in your first example is the same as calling it on an empty string and this is why you get `NULL`.

Each call to `strtok` gives you the token based on your chosen delimiter. In your 1st try:

```
char name[] = "[name]";
char *token = strtok(name, "[");
char *token2 = strtok(NULL, "]");
```

The delimiter you chose is `"["` so the 1st call to `strtok` will get `"name]"`, since this is the first token in the string (remember that the string starts with a delimiter). The second will get NULL, since `"name]"` was the end of your original string and invoking `strotk()` now is like invoking it on an empty string.

*`strtok()` uses a static buffer that holds your original string and each invocation "uses" another part of that buffer. After your 1st call, the function "used" the entire buffer.*

In your 2nd try:

```
char line[] = "Hello [name]";
char *tok = strtok(line, "[");
char *tok2 = strtok(NULL, "]");
```

You call `strtok` on a string with the delimiter in the middle of it, so you get a token AND you still have a string left in the static buffer used by the function. That enables the 2nd call of `strtok()` to return a valid token instead of `NULL`.

Comment: That makes sense. I will try to come up with a solution now to get the content inside the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply trying to extract the contents between a single-pair of brackets `[...]`, then `strchr` provides a bit more straight-forward way to accomplish the task. When you are calling `strtok` with a single-delimiter (e.g. `'['` and then `']'`), you are essentially doing what you would do with two successive calls to `strchr` with the characters being the same `'['` and then `']'`.

For example the following will parse the string given on the command line for the characters between brackets (`"[some name]"` by default if no argument is given) up to a maximum of `MAXNM` character (including the *nul-terminating* character):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXNM 128

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char *s = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "[some name]",   /* input */
        *p = s,                 /* pointer */
        *ep,                    /* end pointer */
        buf[MAXNM] = "";        /* buffer for result */

    /* if starting and ending bracket are present in input */
    if ((p = strchr (s, '[')) && (ep = strchr (p, ']'))) {
        if (ep - p > MAXNM) {   /* length + 1 > MAXNM ? */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: result too long.\n");
            return 1;
        }
        /* copy betweeen brackets to buf (+1 for char after `[`) */
        strncpy (buf, p + 1, ep - p - 1);  /* ep - p - 1 for length */
        buf[ep - p - 1] = 0;    /* nul terminate, also done via initialization */
        printf ("name : '%s'\n", buf);  /* output the name */
    }
    else
        fprintf (stderr, "error: no enclosing brackets found in input.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

**note:** the benefit of using `strchr` and `strncpy` for paring between fixed delimiters is you do not modify the original string (like `strtok` does). So this method is safe for use with *string literals* or other constant strings.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/brackets
name : 'some name'

$ ./bin/brackets "this [is the name] and more"
name : 'is the name'
```